# Combinatorics: Is this utilizing the pidgeon-hole principle?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

> How many ways can we assign four different jobs to five different
>   employees, assuming it is possible to assign more than one job to any
>   employee?

Or is this as simple as doing $5^4$?

Comment: If each job is assigned exactly once, then $5^4$ is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 4 jobs, for each job you have a choice of 5 people, so yes, it reduces to simply $5^4$.